# using .each in my page says undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, each

I am trying to get a list of the events with name "Party". I also have a list of all of the events, which works fine. So I put this in my pages_controller:

```
@events = Event.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
@upcoming_events = Event.find_by_name("Party")
```

and here's what my homepage looks like:

```
<% if !signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
    <ul class="users">
        <% @upcoming_events.each do |event| %>
            <%= render :partial => 'events/eventhome', :locals => {:event => event} %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Events", events_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>

    <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
    <ul class="users">
        <% render @events %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

for some reason when I do find_by_name it messes up the .each in the homepage. What am I doing wrong? It says .each undefined method.

Comment: The answers below are correct, however i recommend reading through the rails query interface <a href="http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database">here</a> because it will teach you the fundamentals of rails querying and will prevent running into problems like this later on. hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) like your `Event.find_by_name("Party")` returns an instance of your Event class. I think you need:

```
@upcoming_events = Event.where(:name=>"Party")
```

Comment: This worked! When would I use dynamic finders? For example, I already pass @events to the page, which contains all events. Would I use dynamic finders to search through the events on the homepage? What is the proper way of doing it since I already pass the page a list of all events. Do I also pass it a list of filtered events? Seems repetitive.

Answer (score 4):

[lucapette's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706224/using-each-in-my-page-says-undefined-method/7706267#7706267) as contains the correct reason for this.

You can however use a dynamic finder to find these, you can use find_all_by_*

```
@upcoming_events = Event.find_all_by_name("Party")
```

Which will achieve the same result.

Comment: You're absolutely right but I feel using where is more rails 3.x way :D